# Does Google Cloud App Engine have a special Node.js runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I tried to deploy my Node.js app on Google Cloud using a flexible App Engine. On my local machine the project runs without errors, but on the cloud, it produces strange errors

Like the one, where I need to `require` the `URL` class, otherwise it's undefined, while on my machine it works without the `require`. Another one I still couldn't figure out is when I `Proxy` the global `Promise` object, it comes back as a function, but mongoose fails to load, because `global.Promise` is not a function.

I'm on the latest Node LTS version and using Yarn, so the dependencies definitely have the correct version. Is there a different Node.js runtime I'm not aware of? Or is it an environment setting I can set?

Edit: These errors happen during build (maybe that has something to do with it?)

Comment: strange at https://repl.it/languages/nodejs URL is also undefined althoug the docs say its a global since version 10.

Comment: Can it be the difference between Linux and Windows versions? I use Windows, while GCloud and repl.it is Linux.

Comment: To [specify runtime, npm, yarn versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#engines) for deployment to match that ones used in your test local environment

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the Google Cloud Builder doesn't use the latest node version by default. I needed to specify it in the `cloudbuilder.yaml`, e.g.:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/yarn:node-10.10.0"
  args: ["install", "--production"]
```